# padding arrays using numpy

Tags: python, numpy

in my program i have a numpy array and do some convolution filtering on it. i am looking for some way to make array padding (and then unpad for output) easily using numpy to avoid boundary checking. i know that scipy can do convolution, but i have reasons to make it by myself. gnuplot.py is used for output.

```
def touch(field, coords, value):
    field[coords[0], coords[1]] = value
    if coords[0] - 1 > 0:
        field[coords[0] - 1, coords[1]] = value / 2
    if coords[1] - 1 > 0:
        field[coords[0], coords[1] - 1] = value / 2
    if coords[0] < field.shape[0] - 1:
        field[coords[0] + 1, coords[1]] = value / 2
    if coords[1] < field.shape[1] - 1:
        field[coords[0], coords[1] + 1] = value / 2
```

Comment: Is that really convolution? That code will overwrite all neighboring cells, without regard to their previous value. What are you *really* trying to do?

Comment: it's kinda triggering function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a `pad` module scheduled for inclusion in Numpy 1.7.0 – see [this ticket](http://projects.scipy.org/numpy/ticket/655). For now, just download it and use its `with_constant` function.

Unpadding is as simple as `field[1:-1, 1:-1]`.

Comment: If you want to edit the answer, padding is now live in 1.7.0. The doc link is here http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html